# Android check internet connection with ping test then display image view if true

Tags: android, loops, imageview, android-imageview, android-internet

Hello I've been reading up about checking the users Internet connection and majority of people are saying completing a ping is the best way to make sure a connection is made.

Currently I can do a simple internet connection check, but ideally in my application I want a continuous loop which if the Internet connection returns true then application will continue as normal but if it returns false then I want it to display my currently hidden image view.

Any assistance on the subject would be most appricated, thank you.

Comment: is this what you want ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts/27312494#27312494